# installing openscenegraph with plugins

Tags: graphics, openscenegraph, scenegraph

I'm having trouble installing openscenegraph with vrml plugins Can anyone provide some suggestions?

I'm working on Snow Leopard, and I downloaded the latest OpenVRML 0.18, and OpenSceneGraph 3.0.1

I can get OpenSceneGraph to work, however, I need to load VRML files, and when I use osg to read the file, it says that it can't find any plugin.

I tried installing OpenVRML by compiling from source, but it fails configuring, since it seems to be unable to fine libboost_thread-mt library file, even though I have it installed, and linking to it works.

Answer (score 1):

OSG picks plugins by extension of the file it's trying to load - if your file ends in .vrml, try changing to .wrl and see if it loads - maybe your installation download had the VRML plugin, but it wasn't finding it.

If you just have a few files, the it'll be easier to use something like:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/meshconv/

to convert them to stl or obj files, rather than building the plugin.  Otherwise, you'll want to consult the OSG mailing list/forum.  Join the forum now, anyways, new users' messages don't often get posted right away.